Error in verify_key function from discord_interactions library for Python: Signature was forged or corrupt
I have this code snippet:
def interactions_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            raw_body = request.body
            signature = request.headers.get('X-Signature-Ed25519')
            timestamp = request.headers.get('X-Signature-Timestamp')

            logger.debug(f"Signature (type: {type(signature)}): {signature}")
            logger.debug(f"Timestamp (type: {type(timestamp)}): {timestamp}")
            logger.debug(f"Raw Body (type: {type(raw_body)}): {raw_body}")

            if not signature or not timestamp:
                return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Missing signature or timestamp'}, status=400)

            try:
                verify_key(raw_body, signature, timestamp, PUBLIC_KEY)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Signature verification failed: {e}")
                return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Signature verification failed'}, status=401)

. . .

And it returns this error on the server logs:
2024-06-29T22:14:41.227687+00:00 app[web.1]: Signature was forged or corrupt
With a status code of 200 OK everytime Discord attempts to send it a POST request for verification (I want my server to be an interactions endpoint for a bot)
I have tried decoding and encoding the keys to bites and strings and it returns different errors each time like "could not concatenate str object to bytes" and viceversa, among other things like debugging and capturing logging info as shown above, but nothing works. Can someone please tell me if I'm missing something? Or if I did something wrong?

The message "Signature was forged or corrupt" is not present anywhere in this code.
Are you sure the error is coming from this code?

I am, as modifying that file is what returns the error messages. It's also the code that's called for on my urls configuration for the endpoint.

the first try block is missing an except.

logger, JsonResponse, verify_key and  PUBLIC_KEY are not defined. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

If you can print the full traceback and include it here, it may help find where the issue is.

Thanks guys, I figured it out. Apparently the library i was using was deffective, so I migrated all the arguments to PyNaCl. Also, when I try to print debugging info or make the logs show me the tracebacks it doesn't show me anything but the error handling messages, but that's another issue.
